# .FormulaR1C1 format with quoted hash mark

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing some VBA codes to write some formulas into excel spreadsheets. There is an compile error if the function contains a hash mark "#". Here is my code:

```
Sheets("CleanedData").Range("B2:B2").Offset(0, a - 1).FormulaR1C1 = 
   "=SUM(IF(LEFT(Collation!C, 1)=" # ", 1, 0))"
```

The editor reports a compile error that "Expected: end of statement" when I wrote this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an output of: `=SUM(IF(LEFT(Collation!C, 1)="#", 1, 0))` you need to escape the `"` within the string by doubling them:

```
.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(IF(LEFT(Collation!C, 1)=""#"", 1, 0))"
```